# Proving 2 properties of the adjoint map $T^*$ on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $(\mathcal{H}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ denote a seperable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with induced norm $\Vert \cdot\Vert$.

Let $T:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ denote a linear, continuous map and let $T^*:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ denote the adjoint map i.e. $T^{*}$ satisfies that
$$\langle T(x), y \rangle = \langle x, T^*(y) \rangle.$$

Consider now the norm
$$
\Vert T\Vert_{\infty} := \sup\{\Vert T(x)  \Vert : x\in \mathcal{H}, \Vert x  \Vert \leq 1 \}.
$$

---

I want to prove two properties in this setup:

(1) $\quad$$\Vert T^* \circ T \Vert_{\infty} = (\Vert T\Vert_{\infty})^2$

(2) $\quad$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Vert T(e_n) \Vert^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Vert T^*(e_n) \Vert^2$

---

I have already proven some properties that may be useful in doing so. Here is a list:

(A) $\quad$ $T^{*}$ is linear and continuous

(B) $\quad$ $(T^*)^* = T$

(C) $\quad$ $\Vert T\Vert_{\infty} = \Vert T^*\Vert_{\infty} $

(D) $\quad$ $\Vert T \circ T \Vert_{\infty} \leq (\Vert T\Vert_{\infty} )^2$

---

**Thoughts so far:**

(1) Using property (C) and (D), we can easily arrive at $\Vert T \circ T^* \Vert_{\infty} \leq (\Vert T\Vert_{\infty} )^2$. I have trouble showing the other inequality however. I was think of maybe utilizing property (B) somehow. But maybe there is a different route entirely, perhaps one where we just show the equality directly?

(2) Here it suffices to show that $\Vert T(e_n) \Vert^2 = \Vert T^*(e_n) \Vert^2$ for all $n$. However whenever I try to write out the norms, my manipulations are not fruitful:

$$
\Vert T(e_n) \Vert^2 = \langle T(e_n), T(e_n) \rangle = \langle T(e_n), T(e_n) \rangle = \langle e_n, T^{*}(T(e_n)) \rangle 
$$
or (using (B))
$$
\Vert T(e_n) \Vert^2 = \langle T(e_n), T(e_n) \rangle = \langle (T^{*})^*(e_n), T(e_n) \rangle = \langle e_n, T^{*}(T(e_n)) \rangle 
$$
Can anyone help me?

**Update**: *I have managed to prove part (2) using Parsevals equation (for Fourier coefficients) and Tonellis theorem. So only (1) remains!*

Comment: Regarding (2), you might want to take a look at the left and right shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. If $R$ denotes the right-shift (i.e. $R(e_n) = e_{n+1}$) and $L$ the left-shift (i.e. $L(e_0) = 0$ and $L(e_n) = e_{n-1}$ otherwise), we have $L^\ast = R$ (verify!), but $0 =\lVert L(e_0) \rVert \neq \lVert R(e_0)\rVert = 1$, so that is why your proof idea cannot work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the reverse inequality in $(1)$, let $f\in \mathcal{H}$ with $||f||\leq 1$, then

\begin{align}
||Tf||^2=\langle Tf, Tf\rangle=\langle T^*T f,f\rangle\leq ||T^*Tf||\cdot  ||f||\leq ||T^*T||_{\infty},
\end{align}
where we used Cauchy-Schwartz in the first inequality. Taking the supremum over all $f$ implies
\begin{align}
||T||_{\infty}^2\leq ||T^*T||_{\infty}.
\end{align}